# Mvc3 listboxfor helper method selected items when editing an entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I am working on a asp.net mvc3 demo app with razor that is hosted on http://portfolio-6.apphb.com/Projects

I have mvc scaffolding, Poco objects as entities and mvc scaffolding running.

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="please enter name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public bool isFeatured { get; set; }
    public bool isDisabled { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select atleast one tag")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

First Problem
From above code you can see I have many to many relation between Project and Tag entities.
Now I have mange to implement New project feature with one bug that is Tags property of Project marked as required but client site validation is not working if you don't select any tag.

Second Problem
Once a project is created with mutliple tags if you decide to edit it how to show the tags selected that are associated with the project???

You can find complete source code at https://github.com/najamsk/PortfolioManger

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage to make validation work and tags are now getting selected while editing a project.

But now I run into another problem lets say I create a new project with tag "asp.net" and later I edit project and choose one tag only "wordpress". Now if i post form model binding works but my context cant update tags collection property of the project? It seems to me it entity framwork making problem here when it finds a complex type property for my Project entity?

```
    public void InsertOrUpdate(Project project)
    {
        if (project.ProjectId == default(int)) {
            // New entity
            foreach (var tag in project.Tags)
            {
                context.Entry(tag).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }
            context.Projects.Add(project);
        } 
        else {
            // Existing entity
            //every property of project entity is 
            //getting updated only tags property left out :(
            context.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```